# Update spider code controlled by scrapyd

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

What is the proper way to install/activate a spider that is controlled by scrapyd?

I install a new spider version using scrapyd-deploy; a job is currently running. Do I have to stop the job using `cancel.json`, then schedule a new job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I wrote a little python script that stops all running spiders. After running this script, I run `scrapyd-deploy`, then relaunch my spiders.
I am still not sure if this is the way scrapy pros would do it, though, but it looks sensible to me.

This is the script (replace the value for `PROJECT` to suit yours), it requires the `requests` package (`pip install requests`):

```
import requests
import sys
import time


PROJECT = 'crawler'  # replace with your project's name

resp = requests.get("http://localhost:6800/listjobs.json?project=%s" % PROJECT)
list_json = resp.json()
failed = False

count = len(list_json["running"])
if count == 0:
    print "No running spiders found."
    sys.exit(0)

for sp in list_json["running"]:
    # cancel this spider
    r = requests.post("http://localhost:6800/cancel.json", data={"project":PROJECT, "job": sp["id"]})
    print "Sent cancel request for %s %s" % (sp["spider"], sp["id"])
    print "Status: %s" % r.json()
    if r.json()["status"] != "ok":
        print "ERROR: Failed to stop spider %s" % sp["spider"]
        failed = True

if failed:
    sys.exit(1)

# poll running spiders and wait until all spiders are down
while count:
    time.sleep(2)
    resp = requests.get("http://localhost:6800/listjobs.json?project=%s" % PROJECT)
    count = len(resp.json()["running"])
    print "%d spiders still running" % count
```